# Google Spreadsheet formula, MINUS?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns:

```
| ITEM | COST | SUBTOTAL |
```

Subtotal, for example, is `1000` to start, like:

```
--------------------------
| ITEM | COST | SUBTOTAL |
--------------------------
|      |      | 1000     |
```

Then I want to be able to add an item like:

```
--------------------------
| ITEM | COST | SUBTOTAL |
--------------------------
|      |      | 1000     |
| item | 50   |          |
```

I want subtotal to update now.

I know I can do:

```
MINUS(B3,C2)
```

But I want it to be dynamic like:

```
MINUS(BX,CX)
```

Where `BX` is `this` B and `CX` is `this` C -1 row (the row above the current one to subtract one)

How can I do this with Google Sheets?

Answer (score 7):

Simply copy your formula from that cell to each cell below. Copying formulas with relative references (those without `$`) adjusts them automatically.

I think you have your coordinates backwards, though. Cell C2 contains "1000" and cell B3 contains "50", so your formula in C3 should be `=MINUS(C2,B3)` (or `=C2-B3`).

Comment: Oops, yes, it is backwards! How do I make "relative" refs and not absolute ones?

Comment: Nevermind! Yes this is easy, just copy and paste and it knows!

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B, 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*{C2; B3:B*-1}), 
 SIGN({C2; B3:B*-1})^2), IFERROR(1/0))), "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: running total minus